# When should I use RAA in natural deduction proofs?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I can't understand exactly when should I use RAA (*reductio ad absurdum*) rule in natural deduction proofs? What situation should "trigger" me to think "Now it's time to use RAA"?

Comment: When you have no other strategies available... then try RAA.

Comment: Do you include also "non invertible rules" in available strategies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What situation should "trigger" me to think "Now it's time to use RAA"?

I can think of $4$ explicit situations:

1. Your goal is the negation of something. If you goal is $\neg \varphi$, assume $\varphi$ and see if you can get a contradiction
2. Your goal is some atomic statement $P$: Assume $\neg P$, get a contradiction, get $\neg \neg P$ using RAA, and finally derive $P$ from $\neg \neg P$ (classical logics typically have a $\neg \ Elim$ rule for this)
3. Your goal is a disjunction $\varphi \lor \psi$ ... and you don't have any disjunction that you can work with (if you do have a disjunction, set up a $\lor \ Elim$ on that one.). The nice thing about doing an RAA here is that once you assume $\neg ( \varphi \lor \psi)$, you should be able to derive both $\neg \varphi$ and $\neg \psi$ (using two RAA proofs themselves!), and now you have some useful stuff to work with on your way to a contradiction.
4. Your goal is an existential $\exists x \ \varphi(x)$ ... and you don't have some other existential to work with (if you do have another existential, set up a $\lor \ Elim$ on that one.). So here the assumption will be $\neg \exists x \ \varphi(x)$ which, with a bit of work (and probably another RAA inside) should allow you to prove $\forall x \ \neg \varphi(x)$ ... and that will be useful to try and get to a contradiction given whatever else you have.

Comment: Great answer thanks. Point 3 remembered me that the exclude middle proof use RAA in this way.

Comment: Can I ask you if this is the case . I have to proof {A => (-B or C), C=> B, D=> B} -> B or -(A and B)  but I'm struggling to do it.

Comment: @Maicake Your goal is a disjunction ... and you don't have a disjunction to work with? Sounds like a job for RAA!  That is, assume the negation of that, and see if that leads to a contradiction. Also, from the negation of that you can quickly infer $\neg B$ as well as $A \land B$ .... from which the contradiction almost immediately follows .... so you're not even using any of the premises ... are you sure you wrote that out correctly?

Comment: I solved it using Exclude Middle rule as first move. How can you infer (using natural deduction steps) infer -B and A /\ B from    -(B \/ -(A and B)) ?

Comment: @Maicake For ~B:  OK, that's a negation .... sounds like a job for ... RAA! So, assume B. Then by v Intro you get B v ~(A & B), and that contradicts ~(B v ~(A & B)). So, by RAA we can conclude ~B.  We can get A&B the exact same way: Assume ~(A &B). By v Intro, you can get B v ~(A & B), and that contradicts ~(B v ~(A & B)). So, by RAA we can conclude ~~(A &B), and by & Elim we get A&B.  Yes, RAA is your friend! :)